# How do I exclude certain parts of a .Include on a condition?

Tags: linq

We are trying to exclude certain data from our queries based on a condition, but we can't seem to get it right. Our current code looks like this:

```
var PullData = _context.RequestInformation.Include(x => x.RequestMinistry)
                        .Include(x => x.RequestApps)
                        .ThenInclude(x => x.RequestAppDataChoices)
                        .Where(x => x.RequestStatus != "Cancelled With Reason")
                        .Where(y => y.RequestApps.SelectMany(x => x.RequestAppDataChoices)
                        .Where(s => s.AppDataChoiceDl.Contains(groupName))
                        .Where(a => a.RequestApps.AppProvisioningCompleteTime != null)
                        .Where(aa => aa.RequestApps.AppTeamCompleteTime == null)
                        .Where(ab => !ab.RequestApps.AppStatus.Contains("Rejected")).Any());
```

This is fine as long as we are trying to pull all of the "RequestApps" with each set of "RequestInformation", however if we want to pull just specific applications based on conditions, it doesn't work. We want to only show the request apps based on the the conditions above (The appdatachoicedl contains "groupname", the completetime != null while the other completetime IS null, and that the status is not rejected), but instead, we are getting all the request information that matches those conditions.

I tried something like this, but it still doesn't quite give me the results I need. It gives me random blank results as well:

```
var PullDataV2 = from reqInfo in _context.RequestInformation
            join RA in _context.RequestApps on reqInfo.ReqNum equals RA.ReqNum
            join RADC in _context.RequestAppDataChoices on RA.PkId equals RADC.RequestAppsId
            where RADC.AppDataChoiceDl == groupName
            select new RequestInformation()
            {
                ProvisioningCompleteTime = reqInfo.ProvisioningCompleteTime,
                RequestMinistry = reqInfo.RequestMinistry,
                RequestApps = reqInfo.RequestApps,
                UserFirstName = reqInfo.UserFirstName,
                UserLastName = reqInfo.UserLastName,
                SubmitterFirstName = reqInfo.SubmitterFirstName,
                SubmitterLastName = reqInfo.SubmitterLastName,
                RequestStatus = reqInfo.RequestStatus
            };
```

I hope I'm making sense here - I only want the requestapps based on the conditions, not all the request information that is those conditions. RequestApps is a part of the RequestInformation class.

Edit:

Piggybacking off of Roberts comments, I modified his code to look like this, but I am struggling with the last line - I need to be able to make sure that "AppDataChoiceDL" which is a member of RequestAppDataChoices (which is a member of RequestApps) is equal to groupName

```
var PullData = _context.RequestInformation.Include(x => x.RequestMinistry)
                                .Include(x => x.RequestApps)
                                .ThenInclude(x => x.RequestAppDataChoices)
                                .Where(x => x.RequestStatus != "Cancelled With Reason")
                                .Where(x => x.RequestApps.SelectMany(app => app.RequestAppDataChoices)
                                    .Where(a => a.AppDataChoiceDl.Contains(groupName))
                                    .Where(b => b.RequestApps.AppProvisioningCompleteTime != null)
                                    .Where(c => c.RequestApps.AppTeamCompleteTime == null)
                                    .Any(n => !n.RequestApps.AppStatus.Contains("Rejected"))).Select(reqInfo => new RequestInformation
                                {
                                    ProvisioningCompleteTime = reqInfo.ProvisioningCompleteTime,
                                    RequestMinistry = reqInfo.RequestMinistry,
                                    UserFirstName = reqInfo.UserFirstName,
                                    UserLastName = reqInfo.UserLastName,
                                    SubmitterFirstName = reqInfo.SubmitterFirstName,
                                    SubmitterLastName = reqInfo.SubmitterLastName,
                                    RequestStatus = reqInfo.RequestStatus,
                                    RequestApps = reqInfo.RequestApps
                                        .Where(a => a.AppProvisioningCompleteTime != null)
                                        .Where(b => b.AppTeamCompleteTime == null)
                                        .Where(x => !x.AppStatus.Contains("Rejected"))
                                        .Where(b => b.RequestAppDataChoices.Where(a => a.AppDataChoiceDl == groupName))
                                });
```

This throws an error not being able to convert IENUmerable to bool.. maybe I'm selecting my RequestAppDataChoices wrong?

Comment: You can't, not the way you are trying it.  You can't pull only some children of a parent.  You can if you turn the query on it's head so that you pull RequestApps and it's related information, but depending on your data model, that might be better or worse.  `var PullData = _context.RequestApps.Include(x => x.RequestAppDataChoices).Include(x=>x.RequestInformation).ThenInclude(x=>x.RequestMinistry)...`

Comment: Yeah, it that wouldn't quite work for what we are doing. I suppose we could always just exclude the request apps for each set of request information, and then query the request apps separately - but that sounds like it would be a lot slower than just pulling all the information all at once.

Comment: Well you can always project the information back into whatever form you want to process it in once you have the data loaded from the data layer, assuming that is your concern on why it won't work.

Comment: If these are just POCO classes, just filter it out in the projection.  I'll put code in an answer you can look at.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes you have a RequestInformationDto class that closely resembles your RequestInformation class:

```
var PullData = _context.RequestInformation.Include(x => x.RequestMinistry)
  .Include(x => x.RequestApps)
  .ThenInclude(x => x.RequestAppDataChoices)
  .Where(x => x.RequestStatus != "Cancelled With Reason")
  .Where(x => x.RequestApps.SelectMany(app => app.RequestAppDataChoices)
    .Where(x => x.AppDataChoiceDl.Contains(groupName))
    .Where(x => x.RequestApps.AppProvisioningCompleteTime != null)
    .Where(x => x.RequestApps.AppTeamCompleteTime == null)
    .Where(x => !x.RequestApps.AppStatus.Contains("Rejected")).Any())
  .Select(reqInfo => new RequestInformationDto {
    ProvisioningCompleteTime = reqInfo.ProvisioningCompleteTime,
    RequestMinistry = reqInfo.RequestMinistry,
    RequestApps = reqInfo.RequestApps
      .Where(app => app.AppProvisioningCompleteTime != null)
      .Where(app => app.AppTeamCompleteTime == null)
      .Where(app => !app.AppStatus.Contains("Rejected")).Any())
      .ToList()
    UserFirstName = reqInfo.UserFirstName,
    UserLastName = reqInfo.UserLastName,
    SubmitterFirstName = reqInfo.SubmitterFirstName,
    SubmitterLastName = reqInfo.SubmitterLastName,
    RequestStatus = reqInfo.RequestStatus
  });
```

I just noticed this part of your query, which should probably be reworked (or removed) as well:

```
  .Where(x => x.RequestApps.SelectMany(app => app.RequestAppDataChoices)
    .Where(x => x.AppDataChoiceDl.Contains(groupName))
    .Where(x => x.RequestApps.AppProvisioningCompleteTime != null)
    .Where(x => x.RequestApps.AppTeamCompleteTime == null)
    .Where(x => !x.RequestApps.AppStatus.Contains("Rejected")).Any())
```

Comment: Wouldn't the where clauses up above have to be used to narrow down the request information? If we didn't narrow it down like that, the PullData variable would contain RequestInformation that was not relevant to the conditions.

Comment: By the way, the projection makes complete sense now that I see it! I think I might be able to make something work with that.

Comment: Yes, I left the where clause in there so that if there were RequestInformations with no relevant RequestApps, then it wouldn't even return the RequestInformation.  Hopefully the EF provider is smart enough to help reduce the amount of data returned from the server.

Comment: Gotcha. I made some modifications to the code you provided and came up with something that almost compiles, but I'm having trouble with the last line where I'm selecting an appdatachoiceDL, which is a string in the RequestAppDataChoices class of RequestApps.

Answer (score 0):

With Robert McKee's help, I was able to come up with this, that does work:

```
var PullData = _context.RequestInformation.Include(x => x.RequestMinistry)
                                .Include(x => x.RequestApps)
                                .ThenInclude(x => x.RequestAppDataChoices)
                                .Where(x => x.RequestStatus != "Cancelled With Reason")
                                .Where(x => x.RequestApps.SelectMany(app => app.RequestAppDataChoices)
                                    .Where(a => a.AppDataChoiceDl.Contains(groupName))
                                    .Where(b => b.RequestApps.AppProvisioningCompleteTime != null)
                                    .Where(c => c.RequestApps.AppTeamCompleteTime == null)
                                    .Any(n => !n.RequestApps.AppStatus.Contains("Rejected"))).Select(reqInfo => new RequestInformation
                                {
                                    ProvisioningCompleteTime = reqInfo.ProvisioningCompleteTime,
                                    RequestMinistry = reqInfo.RequestMinistry,
                                    UserFirstName = reqInfo.UserFirstName,
                                    UserLastName = reqInfo.UserLastName,
                                    SubmitterFirstName = reqInfo.SubmitterFirstName,
                                    SubmitterLastName = reqInfo.SubmitterLastName,
                                    RequestStatus = reqInfo.RequestStatus,
                                    RequestApps = reqInfo.RequestApps
                                        .Where(a => a.AppProvisioningCompleteTime != null)
                                        .Where(b => b.AppTeamCompleteTime == null)
                                        .Where(x => !x.AppStatus.Contains("Rejected"))
                                        .Where(b => b.RequestAppDataChoices.Any(a => a.AppDataChoiceDl == groupName)).ToList()
                                });
```